# GCP's own guide to solve Transaction ID wraparound protection for PostgreSQL does not work for me

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am getting an error on my PostreSQL instance running on GCP.

It says that "The transaction ID utilization percentage is close to 100% on this instance, after which PostgreSQL will stop accepting write queries."

I am not allowed to to any operations.

GCP however handily points me towards this guide:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/txid-wraparound

I follow it until the point near the beginning were it tells me to drop my tables from pg_temp_* schemas:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnAUz.png)

When I try with this query:

SET cloudsql.enable_maintenance_mode = 'on'; /* get extra transaction ids */
DROP TABLE pg_temp_151.tmp_map_match;

I get the following error:

ERROR:  permission denied for schema pg_temp_151
SQL state: 42501

And thus am stuck not having solved the problem. I have gone through the rest of the tips and tricks as well, it did not solve anything. So I assume this is still the problem.

Any ideas? Your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The error message and manual both mention entering single-user mode, meaning forcibly disconnecting all ongoing sessions except yours. Once those sessions are gone, all their `pg_temp`s are free to be cleaned up by either manually started or automatically triggered [`vacuum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html), not manually dropped.

To manipulate someone's [`pg_temp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-TEMPORARY), you'd have to jack into the session that owns the particular `pg_temp` schema - PostgreSQL isn't designed to allow that even to a superuser. Taking over a session does not mean connecting as the same user, it means hijacking a particular, existing connection.

Your clients need to close their sessions to orphan the `pg_temp`s in order for `vacuum` to pick that up and wipe them. That, or they need to start explicitly dropping their `temp` resources as soon as they are no longer needed, assuming you have control or influence on the client-side code. In that case, you can also consider using regular schemas of your own and put [`unlogged`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-UNLOGGED) objects in them instead, which will allow superusers to inspect and wipe them more easily - same performance, more control, at the price of convenience.

It is possible that the client code relies on the fact that resources created as `temporary` will be *automagically* dropped at the end of the session, while still using a pool that re-uses sessions without closing and reopening them periodically, so ultimately the `drop` never happens.